# Varnish and configuring Apache

Tags: apache, drupal, debian, varnish

I've been trying to install **Varnish** on my virtual Debian server, where I have my own portfolio site and a development environment for building Drupal and Wordpress websites. I'm trying to optimize the speed on Drupal Commerce Kickstart.

I've been reading a lot of documentation about this and I've been narrowing an error which Varnish produces when trying to start and that is that both **Apache and Varnish attempt to listen to port 80** and this does not work.

Every instruction I've read suggest that you adjust Apache's config file to use port 8080 on NameVirtualHost and Listen, but that means that your website does not work on a normal www address but rather you would have to insert :8080 in the end. This would be unacceptable to me atleast.

How can I fix this so that Varnish runs and I Drupal can find it, as it now reports:

```
 The Varnish control terminal is not responding at 127.0.0.1 on port 6082
```

My server reports:

```
 [FAIL] Stopping HTTP accelerator: varnishd failed!
 [....] Starting HTTP accelerator: varnishd
```

My Apache ports.conf is just NameVirtualHost and Listen is 80.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to put varnish in front of apache, you need to point your domain to varnish. Varnish will retrieve data from apache. For users they will request for http://example.com which will go to varnish with default port 80. Varnish will check whether it is already cached or not? If it is cached, it will serve directly. If not, it(varnish) will go to apache (whatever the port is) and fetch, cache and serve.